# Orthonomal set to be an Hilbert basis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $\{e_n\}_{1}^{\infty}$ be a Hilbert basis and $(u_n)_{1}^{\infty}$ an orthonormal set such that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}||e_n-u_n||^2$ converges then $\{u_n\}$ is also a Hilbert basis.

I tried this: there exists $n$ such that $\sum_{i=n}^{\infty}||e_i-u_i||^2 < 1$, $X=A+A^{\perp}$, where $A=span\{e_i\}_{i}^{n-1}$, let  $f \in A^{\perp}$ such that $<f,u_i>=0  ,\forall i\geq n$.

$||f||^2 = \sum_{i=n}^{\infty}|<f,e_i>|^2 = \sum_{i=n}^{\infty}|<f,e_i -u_i + u_i>| \\ = \sum_{i=n}^{\infty}|<f,e_i -u_i>|^2 \leq \sum_{i=n}^{\infty}||f||^2||e_i-u_i||^2 < ||f||^2$

So we can see that $A^{\perp} \cap (span\{u_i\}_{i=n}^{\infty})^{\perp} = 0$, but I dont know where to go from here, because I can't seem to see that these $u_i$ will be in $A^{\perp}$ to conclude that they form an hilbertian base for it. I also know that if $N=(span\{u_i\}_{i=n}^{\infty})$ , since dim$A \in \mathbb{N}$ and dim$N$>dim$A$ we  have that $A^{\perp} \cap N \neq 0$ but this doenst tell me that its a subspace of it .

Any help is aprecciated Thanks in advance,

Comment: I don't see how you know that such an $f$ even exists?

Comment: Im showing that  an element in that intersection has to be zero

Comment: There is reason you cannot prove it: it isn't always true that the $u_i$ will be in $A^\perp$. Subspaces do not have to contain any elements of a basis (think of the line $y = x$ in $\Bbb R^2$, which does not contain either of the canonical basis elements). You are barking up the wrong tree with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining
$$
             Af = \sum_{n}\langle f,e_n\rangle u_n.
$$
Let $C=\sum_{n}\|u_n-e_n\|^2$, and assume that $C < 1$. Then
$$
           Af-f = \sum_{n}\langle f,e_n\rangle u_n-\sum_{n}\langle f,e_n\rangle e_n \\
       = \sum_{n}\langle f,e_n\rangle(u_n-e_n) .
$$
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$
        \|Af-f\|^2 \le \sum_{n}|\langle f,e_n\rangle|^2 \sum_{n}\|u_n-e_n\|^2 
                        = C\|f\|^2
$$
Therefore $\|A-I\| \le \sqrt{C} < 1$, which is enough to prove that $A$ is invertible. In particular $A$ is surjective, which guarantees that $\{ u_n \}$ is a spanning orthonormal set and, hence, is a complete orthonormal set.